# How to get values of a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, return

I am trying to get values from a JSON file using this function:

```
function getarray(){
  $http.get('http://localhost/prebuilt/countries.json')
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.countries = data;
  });
  return data;
}
```

I need these return values to be used in another function in the same control block. The problem is that it doesn't return anything.

my controller starts like this:

```
angular.module('theme.charts-flot', [])
       .controller('FlotChartsController', 
                   ['$scope', 
                    '$timeout', 
                    '$http',
                    '$parse',
                    function ($scope, $timeout, $http, $parse) {
```

and ia m using a template. this is the controller for the chart that is being updated real time.

Comment: Could you show me your controller, because it seems you're trying to solve a problem that's caused by a design that could be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AngularJS you do not have to return the data. It uses data binding, so it is sufficient to assign the data to $scope.countries and its value will be updated.
However, you have to parse the data in the HTTP response like this, if you are not using the default transformation of the response:

```
$scope.countries = JSON.parse(data);
```

If you want to return something you can always return $scope.countries.
The data is out of the local scope of the success function and therefore it will be undefined at the return statement.

Comment: But how can I access this data from a function in the same controller?

Comment: Assign the data to a variable like `$scope.data = data;` and in the other function use `$scope.data`.

Comment: Ok now that works!  then how can i access things inside from the other function? i tried $scope.data[0].time but does not work.

Comment: Remember you have to parse the JSON. To access the fields you can just type `$scope.data.countryId` оr whatever is in the data.

Comment: Thanx for quick replies. I did something like this after parsing the JSON as u have shown in the answer.    value = $scope.data;
       console.log(value[0].time); but it gives a error. "cannot read property 0"

Comment: I think angularjs will parse you the json automatically, when the content type is `application/application/json`.

Comment: Yes, the default transformation does that.

Comment: Yes JSON.parse(data) gives a error. I get a object array when i call $scope.data. But i cannot get its contents.

Comment: OK, sorry for the misleading. Thanks to @23tux

Comment: But Thanx you pretty much solved the problem. (y)